# Angular CLI does not recompile on save with IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, angular-cli

I have the following issue - I am using Angular CLI (v1.1.1) with IntelliJ (v2017.1.4) and sometimes when I save a file my changes are not reflected so I need to restart the `ng serve` command. In these cases there is no `[rendered]` indicator in the console.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems angular-cli/webpack still don't correctly handle 'safe writes'. Please try disabling **Use "safe write"** in `File | Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings`